# Configure pdf-tools in Emacs running on MacOS

Tags: pdf, emacs

I am unable to successfully utilize the pdf-tools package.

Environment:

- macOS Monterey 12.0.1
- Emacs 27.2

To the best of my understanding, I have followed the installation instructions as outline on https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools:

- I've installed and confirmed that the installations of `poppler` and `automake` are up-to-date
- Though it doesn't seem to be required for the MacOS install, I've installed and confirmed that the installations of `gcc` and `glib` are up-to-date.
- I've set the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` in the `init.el` file using `setenv` and confirmed its settings using `getenv`

```
(setenv "PKG_CONFIG_PATH" "/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.8/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig")
```

When I try to execute `pdf-tools-install` and select `y` in response to the question "Need to (re)build the epdfinfo program, do it now?" I get a compilation error which reads:

> mode: compilation; default-directory: "~/.emacs.d/elpa/pdf-tools-20211110.513/build/server/"
> Comint started at Thu Dec  2 09:17:05

> /Users/username/.emacs.d/elpa/pdf-tools-20211110.513/build/server/autobuild -i /Users/username/.emacs.d/elpa/pdf-tools-20211110.513/
> Failed to recognize this system, trying to continue.

> Configuring and compiling

> No such program: autoreconf

> Comint exited abnormally with code 1 at Thu Dec  2 09:17:05

I have confirmed that the referenced directory exits and that `autoreconf` is installed and up-to-date.

Answer (score 3):

For a long while, I had a working `pdf-tools` setup on my Mac (thank you Andreas Politz and all the other contributors for such a fabulous tool). Suddenly, I don´t really know how or why, it stopped working. I also deleted my homebrew HEAD version of pdf-tools, which made things worse, because I have never again managed to install pdf-tools from Homebrew.

I tried many tweaks, until, finally, I believe the trick that really got things running again was twofold: 1.- reinstalling my Command Line Tools (`xcode-select --install`) and 2.- setting the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`  inside the `init.el` file to everything that seemed to matter (and downloading XQuartz to get a X11 environment, with the only purpose of having `renderproto` in the system; it may have been available in an easier way, but it was only like this that I managed to do it).

Here are all the key steps involved in getting pdf-tools back to work in my MacOS Monterey 12.5 running Emacs 28.1 :-)

1. After making sure to have (re)installed Apple's Command Line Tools (`xcode-select --install`), download and install XQuartz to get X11 in your Mac (this might be unnecessary, but it seemed to help me).
2. In case you haven't already, install other dependencies through homebrew:

   ```
     brew install poppler automake pkg-config
   ```
3. Through `M-x list-packages`, install `pdf-tools`.
4. In your `init.el` file, set the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` using `setenv`:

   ```
     (setenv "PKG_CONFIG_PATH" "/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.12/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/X11/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Cellar/poppler/22.06.0_1/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/X11/share/pkgconfig")
   ```

   Of course, you will have to use your own version numbers and update them every time you upgrade `zlib` and `poppler`. (`zlib` now ships with mac OS. If like me you're on mac OS 12.6 or later--and most probably even earlier--you can use `/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib/pkgconfig:`, which won't have to be updated manually).
5. Personally, I did all this through the `use-package` configuration macro that helps organize the `init.el` file:

   ```
     (use-package pdf-tools
      :ensure t
      :config
      (setenv "PKG_CONFIG_PATH" "/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.12/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/X11/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Cellar/poppler/22.06.0_1/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/X11/share/pkgconfig")
      (pdf-tools-install)
      (custom-set-variables          
       '(pdf-tools-handle-upgrades t)))
   ```
6. Close **Emacs** and and re open it in the **Terminal** and, type `y` when prompted to "**(re)build the epdfinfo program**".  (For some reason, rebuilding the epdfinfo program seems to work better in the Terminal than in the GUI version of Emacs).

That's all it should take to get `pdf-tools` to work. It did for me, anyway.

(I made an update to this answer on Aug 25th, 2023. BTW, I'm now running Mac OS Ventura 13.5.)

Comment: This has helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try installing the package 'autoconf' the same way you installed 'automake'.